# Angular 4 material header sort issue

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, angular-cdk

I have used angular 4 material for table. There are two issue I am facing 
1. when  sort a table it shows description of sorting order at header. I want to remove it.
[image]

here its shows "Sorted by ascending order.". I have used ngx modal theme from 
http://akveo.com/ngx-admin/#/pages/

```js
import {Component, ViewChild,Input} from '@angular/core';
import {MatTableDataSource, MatSort,MatPaginator} from '@angular/material';
import { AlertDetailsService } from '../../../@core/data/alert-details.service';
import {DataSource } from '@angular/cdk/table';
import {NgbModal, NgbActiveModal,ModalDismissReasons} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import {ModalComponents} from '../modal/modal.component'; 
import { ModalComponentsAlert} from '../alertmodal/modal.component'
/**
 * @title Table with sorting
 */
@Component({
  selector: 'alerts',
  templateUrl: './alerts.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./alerts.component.scss']
})
export class AlertsComponent {
  
  displayedColumns = ['position', 'name', 'weight', 'symbol'];
  dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(ELEMENT_DATA);

  @ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort;

  /**
   * Set the sort after the view init since this component will
   * be able to query its view for the initialized sort.
   */
  ngAfterViewInit()
  {
      this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
  }
}

export interface Element
{
  name: string;
  position: number;
  weight: number;
  symbol: string;
}

const ELEMENT_DATA: Element[] = [
  {
      position: 1,
      name    : 'Hydrogen',
      weight  : 1.0079,
      symbol  : 'H'
  },
  {
      position: 2,
      name    : 'Helium',
      weight  : 4.0026,
      symbol  : 'He'
  },
  {
      position: 3,
      name    : 'Lithium',
      weight  : 6.941,
      symbol  : 'Li'
  },
  {
      position: 4,
      name    : 'Beryllium',
      weight  : 9.0122,
      symbol  : 'Be'
  },
  {
      position: 5,
      name    : 'Boron',
      weight  : 10.811,
      symbol  : 'B'
  },
  {
      position: 6,
      name    : 'Carbon',
      weight  : 12.0107,
      symbol  : 'C'
  },
  {
      position: 7,
      name    : 'Nitrogen',
      weight  : 14.0067,
      symbol  : 'N'
  },
  {
      position: 8,
      name    : 'Oxygen',
      weight  : 15.9994,
      symbol  : 'O'
  },
  {
      position: 9,
      name    : 'Fluorine',
      weight  : 18.9984,
      symbol  : 'F'
  },
  {
      position: 10,
      name    : 'Neon',
      weight  : 20.1797,
      symbol  : 'Ne'
  },
  {
      position: 11,
      name    : 'Sodium',
      weight  : 22.9897,
      symbol  : 'Na'
  },
  {
      position: 12,
      name    : 'Magnesium',
      weight  : 24.305,
      symbol  : 'Mg'
  },
  {
      position: 13,
      name    : 'Aluminum',
      weight  : 26.9815,
      symbol  : 'Al'
  },
  {
      position: 14,
      name    : 'Silicon',
      weight  : 28.0855,
      symbol  : 'Si'
  },
  {
      position: 15,
      name    : 'Phosphorus',
      weight  : 30.9738,
      symbol  : 'P'
  },
  {
      position: 16,
      name    : 'Sulfur',
      weight  : 32.065,
      symbol  : 'S'
  },
  {
      position: 17,
      name    : 'Chlorine',
      weight  : 35.453,
      symbol  : 'Cl'
  },
  {
      position: 18,
      name    : 'Argon',
      weight  : 39.948,
      symbol  : 'Ar'
  },
  {
      position: 19,
      name    : 'Potassium',
      weight  : 39.0983,
      symbol  : 'K'
  },
  {
      position: 20,
      name    : 'Calcium',
      weight  : 40.078,
      symbol  : 'Ca'
  }
];
```

```css
.example-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-width: 300px;
}

.mat-table {
  overflow: auto;
  max-height: 500px;
}

.mat-header-cell.mat-sort-header-sorted {
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="example-container mat-elevation-z8">
    <mat-table #table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort>

        <!-- Position Column -->
        <ng-container matColumnDef="position">
            <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> No.</mat-header-cell>
            <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.position}}</mat-cell>
        </ng-container>

        <!-- Name Column -->
        <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
            <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Name</mat-header-cell>
            <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.name}}</mat-cell>
        </ng-container>

        <!-- Weight Column -->
        <ng-container matColumnDef="weight">
            <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Weight</mat-header-cell>
            <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.weight}}</mat-cell>
        </ng-container>

        <!-- Color Column -->
        <ng-container matColumnDef="symbol">
            <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Symbol</mat-header-cell>
            <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.symbol}}</mat-cell>
        </ng-container>

        <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
        <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></mat-row>
    </mat-table>
</div>
```

Anyone know about this? I run this code separately without using ngx theme I am able to get proper look and fill but in project I am not able to get it.

Answer (score 2):

There can be 2 reasons why you are getting that sorting message :

1. Material theme css is not imported

   @import '~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/deeppurple-amber.css';
2. The theme you are using forgot to handle the sorting message

---

**Solution :**

```
// import the css
@import '~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/deeppurple-amber.css';
```

**OR** (If you don't want to import style)

```
// add css to component
.cdk-visually-hidden{
  display: none !important;
}

// add this line to @Component
encapsulation : ViewEncapsulation.None
```

**[WORKING DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-table-sorting-msg)** (Without importing css)

You can uncomment the import line from root `styles.css` and remove above code from files check again

Comment: Thank you Vivek. Its working with css .cdk-visually-hidden.

Comment: Working like a champ bro. Very useful answer +1